# Passing a parameter correctly

Tags: javascript

I have a function which loops through a list of json objects. It actually works, but it gives me this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined" pointing to this line:

```
var resValues = result.values;
```

My code is:

```
function onLinkedInLoad() {
    IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth);
}

function onLinkedInAuth() {
    var cpnyID = 2414183; //LinkedIn's testDevCo
    IN.API.Raw("/companies/" + cpnyID + "/updates?event-type=status-update&start=0&count=10&format=json")
        .result(displayUpdates);
}

function displayUpdates(result) {
    var resValues = result.values;
    for (var i in resValues) {
        var share = resValues[i].updateContent.companyStatusUpdate.share;
        console.log(share);
    }
}
```

What do I need to change in order to fix this error?

The json looks something like this:

```
{
  "values": [{
      "updateContent": {
          "companyStatusUpdate": {
              "share": {
                  "content": {
                      "description": "Test description",
                      "eyebrowUrl": "http://linkd.in/…",
                      "shortenedUrl": "http://linkd.in/…",
                      "submittedImageUrl": "http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/…",
                      "submittedUrl": "http://linkd.in/…",
                      "thumbnailUrl": "https://media.licdn.com/…",
                      "title": "Best Advice: Take Jobs Others Don't Want"
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }]
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Show us the code where you use `displayUpdates` please, as it seems like you are giving it a wrong parameter.

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there please, as it has no formatting here and it doesn't belong in a comment.

Comment: Your code works correctly in `node`...

Comment: Willem, I can show you the code in action, but it has to be off this site since it contains api keys, etc...

Comment: in your `.result()` function, you just pass along the function `displayupdates` but the function requires a parameter `results`, which you do not provide. As it enters the function `results` is undefined. Therefor you get the error ´Cannot read property 'values' from undefined'

Comment: I think if you change it to `.result(displayUpdates(data))` it would work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It doesn't work. I get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined` error...

Comment: I followed LinkedIn's tutorial here: https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/javascript-api-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this errors appeared because I was listing `displayupdates` further up in the head section where the api key is entered: I removed it so I only have:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    **onLoad: onLinkedInLoad, onLinkedInAuth**
    authorize: true
 </script>
```